# Is has a faster way to perform multiplication of two matrices in GF(256)?

Tags: matlab, matrix, mex

I have two matrices A,B, with double type. I want to perform a multiplication of these matrices in Galois field (256) by using MATLAB. The result with return a double type. This is my code

```
%% Two random matrices
A=randi(255,[1024 1024]);
B=randi(255,[1024 1]);
%% Conver to Galois field (256) and perform multiplication
C =gf(A, 8)*gf(B, 8);
%% Conver to doulbe type
D=double(C.x);
```

In my code, I need two steps: convert from double to GF(256) and then convert gf(256) to double again. I think it will take more time than a direct way. Do we have any direct way to perform the multiplication of two matrices in GF(256)? It maybe faster than my code. It may use mex code, it is fine.Thank all